# relationships with multiple level eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am making an inventory system and I have a master Inventory table and in the other I have the detail of that inventory and in the detail of this table I put in which surcusal is located, but I do not know how to show information about that branch until now. Up to here, I tried some relationships there but it didn't show me anything.

```
[
{
"id_inventory_entry":1,
"invoice_document":"\/document\/invoice\/2021\/01\/01\/askljfowowjw.jpg",
"invoice_correlative":"4334493",
"total_buy":1500,
"detail":[
{
"id_inventory_entry_detail":1,
"id_product":1,
"id_inventory_entry":1,
**"id_branch":1,**
"sale_price":50,
"purchase_price":10
},
{
"id_inventory_entry_detail":2,
"id_product":1,
"id_inventory_entry":1,
**"id_branch":1,**
"sale_price":50,
"purchase_price":10
}
],
"supplier":{
"name":"Apple",
"address":"California CA",
"phone":"12345678"
}
}
]
```

This json makes it return me but I need a branch [] to return inside detail [] but I don't know how to place it at that level

**this is my model master**

```
class InventoryEntry extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'inventory_entry';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id_inventory_entry',
        'invoice_document',
        'invoice_correlative',
        'total_buy',
        'id_supplier',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'id_supplier','created_at','updated_at'
    ];

    public function detail(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\InventoryEntryDetail','id_inventory_entry','id_inventory_entry');
    }

    public function supplier(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Supplier','id_supplier');
    }
}
```

and this is how i show in **my controller**

```
public function all(){
        return InventoryEntry::with('detail','supplier')->get();
    }
```

and this is the **Detail Model**

```
class InventoryEntryDetail extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'inventory_entry_detail';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id_inventory_entry_detail',
        'id_product',
        'id_inventory_entry',
        'id_branch',
        'sale_price',
        'purchase_price'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
    ];

    protected $primaryKey = 'id_inventory_entry_detail';

    public function branch(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Branch','id_branch');
    }

}
```

any idea how to do it? I appreciate your help

Comment: `return InventoryEntry::with('detail','supplier', 'detail.branch')->get();` ?

Comment: Thank you very much brother, I did not imagine how simple, I thank you